# Derefering NULL pointer c++

Tags: c++, pointers, nullpointerexception, malloc, dereference

I get the warning: Derefering NULL pointer 'ch' on lines 2, 4

I don't understand why. Can someone help me out?

```
char *my_alloc(size_t size) {
   char *ch  = (char *)malloc(size);
   //FIXED: If malloc fails -> exit program
   if(*ch == NULL){
       exit(0);
   }
   return ch;
}
```

Comment: `NULL` is deprecated in c++, use `nullptr` instead. Also `new` should be used in c++ instead of `malloc`. And program allocating and returning pointer should return smart pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if(ch == NULL)` is what you need

you dereference `ch` at the code `*ch` inside `if`

---

`ch == NULL` check whether `ch` is `NULL`

`*ch == NULL` check whether the item point by `ch` is `NULL`

Comment: and I think what you get is `exception`, not `warning`

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why?

Comment: In case you ask me why I think you get an `exception` : compiler will not know `ch` is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

For c++ (what you report using in your question) the answer is

```
char *ch  = new char[size];
```

followed by a `delete[] ch` at some point.

You then don't need to check if the result is null as it will throw if it failed.